# How to share large files between two microservices in Mesos?

Tags: microservices, mesos

I have a mesos cluster and I need to run two types of microservices, one is producing very large files (might be more than 2GB for file) the other one is analyzing those files. The analyzing microservice is taking more time than the producer service.
After the analysis service is done - the file can be deleted.

I thought of two options:

1. NFS - producer service creates all files on NFS and the analysis service is taking it directly from the shared folder. (I'm concerned that this approach will consume all internal bandwidth in my cluster)
2. Local Disk (my preferred) - in this case I need to somehow enforce the analysis micoroservice to run on the same Mesos slave as the producer service that created this specific file. (I'm not sure this approach is possible)

What would be best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can be implemented in different ways, depending on your requirements:

- If you want to be able to handle a host (agent) failure, I think there is no other way than using a shared filesystem such as NFS. Otherwise, if you use Marathon to schedule your Microservices, the task will be restarted on another agent (where the data isn't locally available). Also, you would then need to make sure that the same mount points are available on each agent, and use these as host volumes in your containers. Unfortunately, the POD feature availability for co-locating tasks starts to be available in Mesos 1.1.0 and Marathon 1.4 (not yet finally released), as a side note...
- If you don't care about host (agent) failures, then you possible could co-locate the two Microservices on the same agent if you use [hostname constraints](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/constraints.html#cluster-operator) in Marathon, and mount the host volumes which then can be shared across the services. I guess you'd need some orchestration to only start the analysis service only after the producing service has finished.